# Difference between Jettison and Jackson in JBoss

Tags: json, jackson, jboss7.x, jettison, badgerfish

What is the fundmental difference between using RestEasy JSON Provider Jettison (**Badgerfish mapping**) over **Jackson**?

What is is pros and cons of using the one over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jettison is old.

Jackson is arguably the standard Java Library for processing JSON. Jackson is included in Glassfish.

Also some developers has warned me to stay off Badgerfish.

You can implement Jackson in Resteasy, see [here.](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/json.html)

Comment: What are the reasons to "stay off Badgerfish" ?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Which_mappings_.28Badgerfish.2C_natural.2C_....29_does_Jackson_implement.3F

Which mappings (Badgerfish, natural, ...) does Jackson implement?

None. Jackson is "100% JSON" and does not try to imitate or emulate XML. Property name mapping is based on standard Java Bean naming convention (although can be overridden using annotations or custom naming strategy).

There are some support compatibility features -- such as ability to optionally use JAXB annotations -- but fundamentally Jackson is a pure JSON/Java data mapper and tries to minimize impedance between JSON and Java data models.

Comment: Only explains that Jackson is its own pure JSON provider.

Comment: That is why I added the disclaimer about my ignorance. :) sorry I couldn't help